# Versioning builds/releases in TFS 2017

Tags: tfs, asp.net-core, versioning

I have an ASP.NET Core 2.0 project in TFS 2017, and I'd like to specify a version number when our project builds (whenever changes are pushed to master). Is there a simple way to accomplish this? I found several tools that seem to be for this, but I can't figure out how to use them. ([GitVersion](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=gittools.gitversion) | [Semantic Versioning Build and Release Tasks](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=geeklearningio.gl-vsts-tasks-semver))

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a [CI build](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/concepts/definitions/build/triggers) or [CD release](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/concepts/definitions/release/triggers) against the master, then it will trigger the build/release whenever changes are pushed to master.

For versioning the .Net Core project, you can reference this article : [Versioning .NET Core in Visual Studio Team Services](https://sgryphon.wordpress.com/2017/02/24/versioning-net-core-in-visual-studio-team-services/)

For the GitVersion Usage, please refer to this link: http://gitversion.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage/usage/

Besides, you can also use the [.NET Core CLI tool](https://github.com/TAGC/dotnet-setversion) to update the version information in .NET Core *.csproj files.